# Is it appropriate to keep adding before a commit?

Tags: git

I'm still new to git and I'm reading a lot in the docs trying to figure out the practicals. When want to store my files onto the server , I go like this.

```
git add .
git commit --message "Poof goes the dynamite"
git push repo stuff
```

I called my remote *repo* instead of *origin* and *stuff* is my branch (like *dev* or *development*).

It works. But I wonder if this is the appropriate approach or if I'm missing the correct way to use git. It seems so mundane and repetitive to keep adding the files over and over again. It feels like if saving a modified file should already trigger the version control mechanism to mark its status as *commitable*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have to 'git add' a file each time it gets committed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940673/do-i-have-to-git-add-a-file-each-time-it-gets-committed)

Comment: Think of the "add" command as not adding a *file*, but adding a *change* to the commit you're about to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct workflow. Oftentimes, when working with large projects, you end up touching a large number of files, but may want to separate them out into different commits.

Ideally, each commit should represent one logical change, so blanket-adding everything may not be what you want.